# Why is 'child_added' being called twice on my firebaseObject

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire

I'm wiring up a call back to a `$firebaseArray`'s `child_added` event by using this code in the `$loaded` callback.

```
console.debug('setting up watch on tasks');
this.tasks.$watch((args) => {
    console.debug('tasks.$watch', args);
});
```

I've confirmed I'm only getting this once in the console

```
setting up watch on tasks
```

For each child I then subsequently add using `tasks.$save`, I get the following output in the console.

```
tasks.$watch Object {event: "child_added", key: "-KltVJXPe4tX0m3Vj5Gm", prevChild: "-KltVGNv6K0yNXU8W0W6"}
tasks.$watch Object {event: "child_added", key: "-KltVJXPe4tX0m3Vj5Gm"}
```

It seems significant that there's a `prevChild` in the first one but not the second one.  In fact the [`$firebaseObject.$watch` documentation](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/api.html#angularfire-firebasearray-watchcb-context) says that you should expect a `prevChild` argument. Any ideas?

Comment: Sometimes when you listen for changes (`child_added`), you can just create a loop that continues to make changes because a change just happened. Be careful, check that.

Comment: Seems like that would be infinite then, no?

Comment: Correct, thats why I am not sure, just something to look for. Post your `child_added` code.